# animate background image in horizontal scrollview item click

Tags: android, animation

I need to animate a background view either left to right or right to left on in a horizontal scroll view item click. So it may indicate the selected item to user.

I am currently taking the absolute screen positions of each view on screen and translating them to there x and y positions on item click.

```
TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(xFrom, xTo, yFrom, yTo);
animation.setDuration(1000);  
animation.setRepeatCount(0); 
animation.setRepeatMode(2); 
animation.setFillAfter(true);
mScroller.startAnimation(animation);
```

But i am failed to achieve the scenario?

Answer (score 0):

So, I have achieve the scenario with ObjectAnimator.

`ObjectAnimator objectAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mSliderMember,"translationX", xFrom, xTo);
objectAnimator.setDuration(1000);  // animation duration
objectAnimator.start();`